# Function call with stdin or /dev/null if empty

Tags: bash, shell-script, mailx

I'm trying to make a Bash function like this:

```bsh
function send_email {
  local DEFAULT_EMAIL='Something@Somplace.com'
  local email_subject="${1:-No subject line set, please check $0 on $(hostname -f)}"
  local email_from="${2:-$DEFAULT_EMAIL}"
  local email_to="${3:-$DEFAULT_EMAIL}"

  mailx -s "$email_subect" -r "$email_from" "$email_to"
}
```

If I invoke it with something on stdin  (`echo foo | send_email "bar"`), it works fine, mailx picks up the stdin and sends the mail, which arrives just fine. However, if there is nothing on stdin then mailx waits for input, even with -E set.

If it were just me, I'd just know that the function always needs to have something on stdin to work properly but I need to ensure this is easy to use by people less technical than myself.

Is there a way to rig it up to use stdin if available and use /dev/null if stdin is empty?

Comment: I believe this answer should meet your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456750/how-to-check-if-stdin-is-from-the-terminal-or-a-pipe-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if dd of=stdindata iflag=nonblock >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    mailx -s "$email_subect" -r "$email_from" "$email_to" <stdindata
else
    mailx -s "$email_subect" -r "$email_from" "$email_to" </dev/null
fi
```

Comment: This adds a temp file to clean up, but that's easily managed and otherwise works wonderfully. Thank you for this.

Comment: @OstermanA If this solves your problem then you should accept this answer (unless you want to wait for better ones) so that this question does not look unanswered any more.